# ios while (![_lock tryLock]) crash

Tags: ios, crash, locking

The crash report is here:

```
>Exception Type:  SIGSEGV  
>Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x16b  

>Crashed Thread:  3  
>Thread 3 Crashed:  
>0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000195e7bbc8 objc_msgSend + 8  
>1   MSProject                           0x00000001001888a4 -[MStateDataAnalysis stopRecogniseTask] (MStateDataAnalysis.m:85)  
>.....  
>7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001964e5954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16  
>8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001964fc010 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 2052  
>9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001964e7abc _dispatch_source_invoke + 288  
>10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001964f2318 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720  
>11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001964f3c4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108  
>12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001966c522c _pthread_wqthread + 816  
>13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001966c4ef0 start_wqthread + 4
```

The [MStateDataAnalysis stopRecogniseTask] (MStateDataAnalysis.m:85)  class line 85 is:

```
 85  while (![_lock tryLock]) {  
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];  
  }  
  _resultArray = nil;  
  _metroFlagArray = nil;  
  [_lock unlock];
```

The lock is:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSLock                * lock;
```

Because the _resultArray and _metroFlagArray is used in two thread,so I use lock。But I don't know what's wrong,there are small probability crash.

Comment: Can you show more your codes?

Comment: @anhtu thank you very much! I have provided more codes just now,if it is enough? Beacause my code's logic is complexity, so I just abstract the main and related codes.

Comment: while (![_lock tryLock]) {  
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];  
  } is in main thread?

Comment: DId you try to debug into [_lock tryLock]?

Comment: @anhtu I am so sorry anhtu , I don't understand you. tryLock is a system method ,How could I debug into ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your update. Let me think more.

Comment: @anhtu    Thank you so much~